# Azure hosted Database having a single column cleared at random

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

We have written a c# MVC ASP.NET CORE project which is hosted as an azure app-service and is driven by an azure hosted sql server.

I have the following sql Table as a part of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]               NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Active]              BIT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [TeamID]              INT            NULL,
    [UserType]            INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [UserCpM]             FLOAT (53)     DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CpMSet]              BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentProject]      INT            DEFAULT ((-2)) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentNotes]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TimeStarted]         DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Failure]             BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Failure_Project]     INT            NULL,
    [Failure_TimeStarted] DATETIME       NULL,
    [Failure_TimeEnded]   DATETIME       NULL,
    [Failure_Notes]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_ToTeams] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Teams] ([TeamID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_CurrentProject_ToProjects] FOREIGN KEY ([CurrentProject]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_FailureProject_ToProjects] FOREIGN KEY ([Failure_Project]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectID])
);
```

The `UserCpM` field is an indication of employees cost-per-minute and as such is cleared before displaying to any user who is not of the highest privilege level. Over the last couple of days this field has been randomly resetting itself back to 0 for every entry in the table in the database.

I have hunted through the code and confirmed that on any view where the CpM is cleared it is re-set before saving the User back to the database so I'm fairly certain that that isn't the cause of the issue.

Is there any reason that the context would save it's changes without being told to do so? or alternatively is it possible that it will track changes to anything set from it and transfer them back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason that the context would save it's changes without being told to do so?

No, Azure SQL or SQL Server hosted on Azure will not modify your data.

> is it possible that it will track changes to anything set from it and transfer them back to the database.

I suggest you create a log table and 2 triggers for your Users table. If any updates has been applies on Users table. It triggers will write the operation time and the UserCpM changes to the log table.

Here is a insert trigger code sample.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UsersInsert
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN

    insert into dbo.UserLog(UserID, OriginalUserCpM, NewUserCpm, ModifiedDate)
    select UserID, null, UserCpm, GETDATE() from inserted
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Here is a update trigger code sample.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UsersUpdate
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
    insert into dbo.UserLog(UserID, OriginalUserCpM, NewUserCpm, ModifiedDate)
    select UserID, UserCpm, null, GETDATE() from deleted

    insert into dbo.UserLog(UserID, OriginalUserCpM, NewUserCpm, ModifiedDate)
    select UserID, null, UserCpm, GETDATE() from inserted
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```